# Jade Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in each loop

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this code in my controller retrieving an object from mongo and sending it to the client:

```
 index: function(req, res){
    List.find({user:req.session.user.id}).exec(function foundLists(error, foundLists) {
        if(error) {
            return res.json({error:error});
        } else {
            return res.view({ title:'Lists',lists:foundLists });
        }
    });
 }
```

In my view I do the following:

```
extends ../layout
  block content
    .container
        p #{lists}
```

Which renders:`[object Object],[object Object]`

If I do `p= JSON.stringify(lists)`

It renders:

```
[{"user":"546109c0d640523d1b838a32","name":"third","createdAt":"2014-11-11T19:39:36.966Z","updatedAt":"2014-11-11T19:39:36.966Z","id":"546265f83e856b642e3b3fed"},{"user":"546109c0d640523d1b838a32","name":"forth","createdAt":"2014-11-11T19:42:09.268Z","updatedAt":"2014-11-11T19:42:09.268Z","id":"546266913e856b642e3b3fef"}]
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```
#lists
    each list in lists
       p #{list}
```

But I get this error:
`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I'm using Sails and Jade 1.7.0

Comment: Driving me crazy too :( [What did you see?](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects, so if you do `each list in lists` then `list` is an object. I assume Jade wants a string. If you put `p #{list.name}` or something similar that should work.

If you want to show everything you can try nesting your loops like

```
each list in lists
    each item in list
        p #{item}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occurred when at least one of the items in the lists does not have a `list` property. You can protect this using an if statement:

```
each val in lists
    if val.list
        each item in val
            p #{item}
```